# Replace rows with different number of characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column having strings of different number of characters. Most of rows have the following number of characters:

```
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
```

but there are also rows having different number, for instance

```
xxx.xxx.xxxx
xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like to replace those columns that have a number of characters different from `xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx` with a null value (e.g. NA).
My approach would be to calculate length of `xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx` and then filter rows which have a different number of characters: `df[df['Char']!=len('xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx')]`. But I would need also to replace the values of those rows.
Can you please tell me how to do it?

My column looks like

```
Char 
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xxx.xxx.xxxx
xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
```

and my expected output would be

```
Char 
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
Na
NA
NA
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `loc`

```
df.loc[df['Char'].str.len()!=len('xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx'),'Char']=np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have strings in the those columns which can match the length of your expected sequence. I would suggest you use a regex string to match the value in your string and replace all the ones which do not match your criteria

For example:

```
l = [*df['col']]
l = ['xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xxx.xxx.xxxx',
 'xxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx']

l = [k[0] if len(k)>0 else np.nan for k in [re.findall('\w+.\w+.\w+\s\w+-\w+-\w+', i) for i in l]]

df['col']=l

df['col'] = 

col
'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx',
 'xx.xx.xxxx xx-xx-xx'
```